# Select only rows that are in the range of distance PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, distance

Hey I have a PHP code where I have in every row a certain latitude and longitude and I POST using android app another latitude and longitude, in the php file I have a function that calculates the distance between this two points and return it.
what I want to do is select all the rows from the table that are lower than a specific number I say.
How can I make a select statement that will give me the result I want?

Here is the distance code:

```
$place_lat = $_POST["lat"];
$place_long = $_POST["long"];

$my_lat = "32.21231";
$my_long = "34.1231";

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
   return ($miles * 1.609344);
}
```

How can I run a select command that will select all the rows that are in a range of lets say 50 k"m?

Thanks.

Comment: You have php code? Then show it!

Comment: @Jeff sorry for that, I edited the post can you take a look and help?